# Should I design JSF page bean invoke multiple facade or single facade to interact with multiple modules within the system?

Tags: java, design-patterns, service

I am reading the codes of a system and trying to understand the service layer design.

I observed that for every object(entity to be saved to the database), a set of related classes/implementations will be created as follow:

1. Product.java
2. ProductDAO.java (Interface class)
3. ProductDAOImpl.java
4. ProductService.java (Interface class)
5. ProductServiceImpl.java

Based on a shopping cart example, for every product the customer purchased, I will have to perform the following transaction:

1. Decrease the quantity of the product
2. Save the order
3. Create a notification record for the batch job to send an email to notify the customer

How should I design/implement it?

Method #1

```
public class ShoppingCartPageBeanA {
   private ProductService productService;
   private OrderService orderService;
   private NotificationService notificationService;

   public void submit() {
     productService.decreaseProductTotalQuantity(product);  
     orderService.saveOrder(order);
     notificationService.saveNotification(notification);
   }
}
```

Method #2

```
public class ShoppingCartPageBeanB {
   private ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService;

   public void submit() {
     shoppingCartService.saveOrder(order);
   }
}

public class ShoppingCartServiceImpl {

  private ProductDAO productDAO;
  private OrderDAO orderDAO;
  private NotificationDAO notificationDAO;

  public void saveOrder(Order order) {
        productDAO.decreaseProductTotalQuantity(order.getProduct);
        orderDAO.saveOrder(order);
        notificationDAO.saveNotification(order.getNotification);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #2 is the way to go, as it encapsulates your business logic in service layer, thereby allowing you to follow the DRY (i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Let's say, today, you are implementing the functionality (of placing an order) only for your desktop website. In future, if you need to add the same to your Android app, you'd be able to reuse ShoppingCartService, *if* you go with Method #2. If you were to go with Method #1, you'd have to duplicate your business logic in the app.

Comment: in this case, wouldnt ProductService, OrderService, NotificationService be made redundant, if each module implements it own service layer?

Comment: 'if each module implements it own service layer' is equivalent to 'ProductService, OrderService, NotificationService', i.e. different services for product, order or notification.. i didn't understand your question

Comment: If I am developing 5 types of services on my website, ie. A,B,C,D,E and I implement a Service class for each, i.e. ServiceAImpl, ServiceBImpl etc, wouldnt ProductService, OrderService, NotificationService be made redundant?

Answer (score 2):

As ketan says, I would rather prefer method #2, but I would like to comment something about creating a service layer for every entity.

Although there are other options, It is a good idea to create a DAO for every entity. However I don't think so about creating a Service class (or interface + implementation pair) for every entity.

Doing so, you will be redundant and sometimes get confused about which service class has to be used. When you develop service layer, you have to focus on what functionalities have to be implemented.

For example, if you have `Order`, `Product` and `Client` entities, maybe you only need `ShoppingManager` service class, implementing methods related with shopping functionality such as, creating new order, modifying order, retrieving client orders, ...

There is nothing wrong in having a manager or service class calling another one, but I think it is clever to avoid this, and develop service classes that only call DAO, brokers, WS/REST, etc.